# Searching data for value and copying select cells from that row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a pair of General Ledger accounts to scan for data.  I need to find a key word or phrase from the descriptions and then collect certain bits of data from those lines.
The source tables (there are two) are on separate tabs and the data from that needs to populate 5 other tables of data for analysis.

This is the code I have so far but it is exceedingly slow.  I would like suggestions to speed up the process.  My thought is to load all the data into an array but I am not sure if that would be faster.

The ones on QA Data K need to find the string it is looking for only in the beginning of the cell being evaluated and I am also trying to find a efficient way to do that.

```
Sub Table9052()
Dim i As Integer
Dim wsA As Worksheet: Set wsA = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("QA Data A")
Dim wsK As Worksheet: Set wsK = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("QA Data K")
Dim wsT As Worksheet: Set wsT = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tables")
Dim Locker As String
Dim GC As String
Dim MBD As String
Dim DDSV As String
Dim DDSV As String
Locker = "9052 Electronic Lockers"
GC = "9042 Dunkin Donuts Gift Card"
MBD = "MERCHANT BANKCD DEPOSIT"
DDSV = "DD STORED VALU"
SS = "STARBUCKS STOREDVALU"
ColARow = 3
ColFRow = 3
ColKRow = 3
ColPRow = 3
ColURow = 3

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
loo = 1
For i = 6 To wsA.Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row
    Eval = wsA.Cells(i, 4)
    Temp = wsA.Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row
    If Eval = Locker Then 'If a locker line copy the cells to ELTable
        wsA.Cells(i, 3).Copy wsT.Cells(ColARow, 1) 'Copy Date to column A
        wsA.Cells(i, 4).Copy wsT.Cells(ColARow, 2) 'Copy Desc to column B
        wsA.Cells(i, 5).Copy wsT.Cells(ColARow, 3) 'Copy Ammt to column C
        wsA.Cells(i, 7).Copy wsT.Cells(ColARow, 4) 'Copy Lodge to column D
        ColARow = ColARow + 1
    End If
    If Eval = GC Then 'If a locker line copy the cells to DDCardTable
        wsA.Cells(i, 3).Copy wsT.Cells(ColPRow, 16) 'Copy Date to column A
        wsA.Cells(i, 4).Copy wsT.Cells(ColPRow, 17) 'Copy Desc to column B
        wsA.Cells(i, 5).Copy wsT.Cells(ColPRow, 18) 'Copy Ammt to column C
        wsA.Cells(i, 7).Copy wsT.Cells(ColPRow, 19) 'Copy Lodge to column D
        ColPRow = ColPRow + 1
    End If
If i = loo * 100 Then
    loo = loo + 1
End If
Next i
loo = 1
For i = 6 To wsK.Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row
    Temp = wsK.Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row
    Eval = wsK.Cells(i, 4)
    If Eval = MBD Then 'If a locker line copy the cells to ELTable
        wsK.Cells(i, 3).Copy wsT.Cells(ColFRow, 6) 'Copy Date to column F
        wsK.Cells(i, 4).Copy wsT.Cells(ColFRow, 7) 'Copy Desc to column G
        wsK.Cells(i, 5).Copy wsT.Cells(ColFRow, 8) 'Copy Ammt to column H
        wsK.Cells(i, 7).Copy wsT.Cells(ColFRow, 9) 'Copy Lodge to column I
        ColARow = ColFRow + 1
    End If
    If Eval = DDSV Then 'If a locker line copy the cells to DDCardTable
        wsK.Cells(i, 3).Copy wsT.Cells(ColKRow, 11) 'Copy Date to column K
        wsK.Cells(i, 4).Copy wsT.Cells(ColKRow, 12) 'Copy Desc to column L
        wsK.Cells(i, 5).Copy wsT.Cells(ColKRow, 13) 'Copy Ammt to column M
        wsK.Cells(i, 7).Copy wsT.Cells(ColKRow, 14) 'Copy Lodge to column N
        ColPRow = ColKRow + 1
    End If
    If Eval = SS Then 'If a locker line copy the cells to DDCardTable
        wsK.Cells(i, 3).Copy wsT.Cells(ColURow, 21) 'Copy Date to column U
        wsK.Cells(i, 4).Copy wsT.Cells(ColURow, 22) 'Copy Desc to column V
        wsK.Cells(i, 5).Copy wsT.Cells(ColURow, 23) 'Copy Ammt to column W
        wsK.Cells(i, 7).Copy wsT.Cells(ColURow, 24) 'Copy Lodge to column X
        ColPRow = ColURow + 1
    End If
If i = loo * 100 Then
    loo = loo + 1
End If
Next i
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub`
```

Comment: If you just want tips on how to speed up your working script. This question would be best at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Stack Overflow is moreso for people who are having issues with a specific programming problem.

Comment: if your code works correctly without errors, then submit here for speedup suggestions https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `If Eval Like MBD & "*" Then` will look for cell contents which begin with `MBD`

Comment: Do you need to copy the whole cell (content+formats etc) in each case, or just the values?

Comment: I followed the suggestions and posted there as well. I had not known of that group.
Tim Williams - In answer to your question: All I need is the data from the field.  the formatting and aspects are not of use.